# Article Body Not Displaying When Article Loaded from AMP Cache

Tags: amp-html

When our articles are loaded from Google search using the AMP cache the only thing on the page that shows up is the header image. However when you load the AMP URL directly the entire article content loads correctly.

Example:
[AMP Cache](https://www.google.com/amp/s/amp.slate.com/technology/2018/09/kavanaugh-wikipedia-devils-triangle.html)
[Direct AMP Link](https://amp.slate.com/technology/2018/09/kavanaugh-wikipedia-devils-triangle.html)

I've verified the AMP URL has passed AMP Cache validation using this validator: https://ampbench.appspot.com/validate?url=https%3A%2F%2Famp.slate.com%2Ftechnology%2F2018%2F09%2Fkavanaugh-wikipedia-devils-triangle.html

Has anyone had issues or experience with this? It must have started recently.

Comment: Have you change your AMP page recently?? If yes, than cache needs to updated.
It gets updated when someone request or load the new page.
I have tried to load your page from Google search, It coming as a normal page from the url : www.google.com/amp/s/{your-url}
Ream more about AMP cache : https://developers.google.com/amp/cache/overview (Read the overview part here)

Comment: Hey, thanks for responding. We haven't made any changes to AMP recently. The reason you're getting redirected to our normal page is likely because you're loading it on desktop. You need to hit the AMP cache URL on mobile.